# Already installed pyzmq but still getting "ImportError: No module named zmq"

Tags: python, ipython

I am trying to get ipython notebook run.
I already installed pyzmq.
Do you know why it's still giving this error?

Comment: How did you install ipython? The deps should come with it.

Comment: The error I have is no module named 'zmq.ipkernel'

Answer (score 18):

The only reason you would be seeing that error (having manually installed pyzmq) is if pyzmq was installed to a different pythonpath than where ipython is running from.

If you followed the install instructions, you should have no problems:

```
easy_install ipython pyzmq tornado
# or
pip install ipython pyzmq tornado
```

It is also possible that the installer saw the dependency already satisfied in another location and didn't do anything, and then ipython might be running with a different pythonpath that isn't seeing it. You can force an upgrade of everything:

```
easy_install -U ipython pyzmq tornado
```

Comment: on debian is #apt-get install python-zmq

Comment: Only if you want to use the debian package manager. You can still use easy_install or pip. They are generic python package managers.

Answer (score 4):

```
pip3 uninstall pyzmq
pip3 install pyzmq
```

Worked for me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install jupyter
```

The above assumes you have aliased `pip` to `pip3`.

Answer (score 2):

check what version on python you installed it with

```
python --version
```

When you run the application make sure you are using that **same version** you used to install it with.

The problem for me was that I installed it for python 3.6 but ran it under python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I have all the packages installed & it also shows up in the path but does throw the same  error

```
jabira@ubuntu:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/share/pyshared/zmq', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
>>> 
jabira@ubuntu:~$ ls /usr/share/pyshared/zmq/
core  devices  eventloop  green  __init__.py  log  ssh  tests  utils  web
jabira@ubuntu:~$ less /usr/share/pyshared/zmq/__init__.py 
jabira@ubuntu:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import zmq
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named zmq
>>> 
jabira@ubuntu:~$ dpkg -l|grep zmq
ii  libzmq3                                 3.2.2+dfsg-1lucid                          lightweight messaging kernel (shared library)
ii  python-zmq                              2.2.0.1-1lucid3                            0MQ is a fast messaging library
jabira@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: had to upgrade the package python-zmq_2.1.11-1_amd64.deb  and it worked http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/python-zmq/download

Answer (score 0):

you should add Phython path to windows local variable PATH before install zmq

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to rename my script from zmq.py to anything else.

This happens because using the name zmq.py crates a name conflict with the package as python tries to include the script itself rather than the library as scripts have priority in the include hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I had a file that was trying to `import zmq` that was throwing:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zmq'`

But `pip install zmq` or `pip install pyzmq` kept telling me I had a version already installed, and thus `Requirement already satisfied` at Library/blahblah/Python/3.6 ...

I've already aliased `pip3` to `pip`, but trying `pip3` didn't work either

I wound up having to reset my $PYTHONPATH and deleted that Python 3.6 install I didn't actually need.

After that `pip install pyzmq` STILL didn't work though.

What finally worked was `pip3 install zmq` ... Weird since I already had that aliased, but something w/the paths might still be screwy.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04 and Python 3.9, this did the trick for me:

`sudo apt-get install python3-zmq`

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/100543